# the use of the verb 'fill'

Tags: grammar

Do we ever use the content name directly after the verb, without the name of the thing which is filled with it. Take an example:

---

"Fill in the blanks with a suitable article where necessary." is what we usually write.

---

Can this be: Fill the suitable article where necessary.

---

Secondly in this instruction should there be an 'a' before the word 'article' or 'the' is fine?

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't normally be said.

---

Consider these sentences.

> Fill the bucket with water.
>   Fill the goblet with wine.

In this type of construction, you fill ***the*** *container* ***with*** *filling*.

We can simplify those sentences in different ways:

> ✔ Fill *the bucket*.
>   ✔ Fill *with water*.
>
> ✔ Fill *the goblet*.
>   ✔ Fill *with wine*.

But we can't simplify them in other ways:

> ✘ Fill *with bucket*.
>   ✘ Fill *the water*.
>
> ✘ Fill *with goblet*.
>   ✘ Fill *the wine*.

---

In your sentence we have this:

> Fill in ***the*** *blanks* [container] ***with*** *a suitable article* [filling] where necessary.

So, either of these could be acceptable as a shorter version:

> ✔ Fill in ***the*** *blanks*. [container]
>   ✔ Fill in ***with*** *a suitable article*. [filling]

But the following would not work:

> ✘ Fill in ***with*** *the blanks*. [container]
>   ✘ Fill in ***the*** *suitable article*. [filling]

There are two things that make your shorter version (the second of these two) incorrect:

- It is discussing the thing that will be used as *filling* (not what will be filled)—but without the preposition *with*.
- While a definite article may be fine in some cases, replacing the longer version's indefinite article with a shorter version that uses a definite article changes the meaning.

Comment: You can kinda-sorta do it if you use *in*: "Fill water in the buckets" - but it only works because of strong context: water is obviously something that goes in a bucket.  Phrases like "Fill water in there" or "Fill water inside" might be understood in strong context situations as well but will sound really weird otherwise.